# Ошибка при подключении к Oracle базе на ВМ ORA-12560

Tags: oracle, odbc

не могу решить проблему `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`
База установлена на VM linux / Клиент на Win10.

- С клиента IP VM пингуется
- В `администратор источника данных odbc` - тестовое подключение успешно.
- PL/SQL и Excel - к базе подключаются.

А в SQL*Plus - после ввода учётных данных - `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`.
Аналогичная ошибка при подключении в RStudio.

**Сервер**

> *listner.ora*

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.32.106)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

> *tnsnames.ora*

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.32.106)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.32.106)(PORT = 1521))
```

**Клиент**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.32.106)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В моём случае, получилось подключиться так :
в SQL*PLUS после ввода пароля, нужно дописать `@SID`(название можно найти в файле `tnsnames.ora`)
[community.oracle](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2131327/ora-12560-sqlplus)